# Trying to compare an already established object to two other variables

Tags: java, object, methods

The object i have already is called client1 ( Just a name) and it holds the attribute of (String description, int rating) The String on it is Dark Hair and the rating is 7. This is for a match making program. Anyways i am trying to compare  Client1 ("Dark Hair", 7) in the method getCompatability();
So with this method i want to return the compatibility measures of the two matching characteristics, or simply a zero if the descriptions do not match. So this is what i want to do

public return_type getCompatability(Characteristic otherRating)
{ Take the object's already initiated Dark Hair and 7 and set them to variables so that i may compare them to the second two entered. 
}

Once i have them all in variables, comparing the two will be simple.
Also is there another way to compare Two objects, perhaps  getCompatability(*Object, Object*) That compares the variables of two objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
public class Characteristic {
    private String description;
    private int rating;

    public Client(String description, int rating) {
        this.description = description;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public int getCompatability(Characteristic otherRating) {
        if (description == null && otherRating.description != null || !description.equals(otherRating.description)) {
            return 0;
        }

        int compatability;
        // Perform comparison to calculate "compatability".
        return compatability;
    }
}
```

Then it can be invoked by saying:

```
Characteristic client1 = new Characteristic("Dark Hair", 7);
Characteristic client2 = new Characteristic("Dark Hair", 4);
Characteristic client3 = new Characteristic("Light Hair", 6);
client1.getCompatability(client2); // Returns non-zero compatability since descriptions are the same
client1.getCompatability(client3); // Returns zero compatability since descriptions are different
client2.getCompatability(client3); // Returns zero compatability since descriptions are different
```

Answer (score 0):

may use

```
 client1.getCompatiblity(client2);



eg:
class ClientDetails {
    String description;
    int rating;
    //getter, setter

    public int getCompatibility(Object client) {
        //add null check & obj type check
        ClientDetails client1 = (ClientDetails) client;
        int count = 0;
        if (description.equals(client1.getDescription()) {
           count ++;
        }
        if (rating == client1.getRating()) {
           count ++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```